# Pre-annihilator of the intersection of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $M,N$ be two subspaces of the dual $X^{*}$ of a vector space $X.$ Under what conditions we have $^{\perp}(M\cap N)=(^{\perp}M)+ (^{\perp}N)?$ where $^{\perp} M\subset X$ is the pre-annihilator subspace.

Comment: Pre-annihilator is a non-standard term, you need to include its definition in your question. But more important than that, what have you tried?

Comment: $x\in (^{\perp}M)$ if and only if $f(x)=0$ for every $f\in M.$

Comment: Preannihilator is a fairly standard term in functional analysis.

Comment: What is the context of the question, functional analysis or (finite dimensional) linear algebra?

Comment: Possibly this may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1193823/27978

Comment: @copper.hat  Yes, the context of my question is functional analysis.